# How do I open/forward a port on an Arris TG1672G?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding

Per the results of a traceroute, I can see that the device I want to forward the port for is behind a Netgear WNDR4500 router which is, in turn, behind the Arris TG1672G modem.  Per step 3 at https://openmyip.com/Arris-TG1672G-router-setup, I first need to assign a static IP address.  Using the same IP address that the Netgear router knows, however, I get an error message that it is "an invalid IP address."

The device's address from the router's perspective is 192.168.1.5.  I am confused as to the IP address assignment process from the modem's perspective.  The modem's address is 192.168.0.1 whereas the router's is 192.168.1.1.

Comment: The subnet of the modem is `192.168.0.1` which means it's assigning a IP address to the router within the subnet.  The subnet of the router is `192.168.1.1` which is separate from the address assigned to it by the modem.

Comment: Thanks, @Ramhound.  So how do I add the device IP address of 192.168.1.5 (as seen via the router) so that it is static on the modem?

Comment: The simplest method? Assigned the modem to `192.168.1.1` then disable DHCP on the modem and manually assigned the router which is connected to the modem to `192.168.1.5` this also means you will have to manually assigned any device you connect to the modem.

Comment: To be clear, @Ramhound, you mean to assign the router ```192.168.1.2``` (or any address available for ```192.168.1.x```), correct?  This would allow me to leave the router's subnet basically as is and the device would continue to use ```192.168.1.5```.

Comment: You would have to statically assigned the device `192.168.1.5` or configure the router to assigned DHCP to that subnet. I suggest using DMZ on the Arris modem and forward all traffic to the router provided no other devices are connected to the modem itself.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Ramhound's feedback I was able to figure it out.  In a nutshell, I needed to view the router as a device on the modem's network.  I was incorrectly thinking of it all as a single network and not grokking the concept about "subnets."  So, opening the port on the modem for its static IP address for the router made it all hum.